# Extracting a single value from a tuple in a list in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

So I have a list of tuples

```
lis = [(5,6), (5,3), (5,2)]
```

How would I extract the first value of the tuple i.e 5.

I know that you do head lis to get the head but this returns (5,6), I would just like the 5.

The bigger picture is to be able to obtain the head of a list of tuples and compare it to every value in another list of tuples to see if it matches.

Answer (score 2):

That's simple, just use the `fst` function for extracting the first value from the tuple:

```
λ> let lis = [(5,6), (5,3), (5,2)]
λ> fst $ head lis
5
```

Comment: But say I wanted to use this in a function I get Syntax error in declaration (unexpected symbol "$")

Comment: @Richard can you make an SSCCE?

Comment: No, I'm not sure what that is

Comment: @Richard, write a small, self-contained example of the sort of code you want to write. Ideally, it should compile. But in general, having a description of part of an error message without the code that led to it will not get you a useful answer.

Comment: Thefourtheye has provided the final bit of code but it still produces an error

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to use a lamba in another expression:

```
 (\(x, _) -> x) (head lis)
```

Or this if you want a function on its own:

```
 first :: (a, b) -> a
 first (x, _) = x
```

There is a function that does the same called `fst`, though.